# create figures with css

Tags: css

I'm looking to do it only with CSS. But when the background color changes, do not affect.
[image]

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: how to do it in css (the image) @forthe

Comment: Please add your attempt to solve the problem.  It's also difficult to understand what you're trying to do - do you want to recreate the image?  What do you mean by "when the background color changes"?  See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I think that this what you want

```css
.container {
      position:relative;
      width: 500px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .circle {
      position: absolute;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: white;
      left: 50%;
       transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete. It should stand on it's own without the need to go to a third party site like codepen. Use the `<>` button in the question editor to create a SO Snippet, which is similar  to codepen but embeded in your answer